# ActiveRecord vs SQL with sub select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I found this query easier if done with SQL

```
select Topics.subject, shortcode, (select count(*) from votes where Votes.Topic_Id = Topics.Id ) as votes from Topics
where url like 'http://test.com%'
ORDER BY votes desc;
```

Using ActiveRecord, I think there should be a more elegant.. or at least possible way to do it. Any suggestions?

I started with this, which worked, but didn't get to the next steps, instead used:

```
t = Topic.find(:all, :conditions => "url like 'http://test.com%'")
```

Comment: It might be easier to help you craft a solution with a bit more information on your schema :)

Comment: Ah.. I thought with the full sql select it could be translated ActiveRecord?  These are the only fields/statements I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get topics with votes:

```
Topic.where('url like :url', :url => 'http://test.com%').
      joins(:votes).
      select('topics.*, count(votes.id) as votes')
```

Note that this will only work in MySql.  For PostgreSQL, you need to specify the group clause:

```
Topic.where('url like :url', :url => 'http://test.com%').
      joins(:votes).
      group(Topic.column_names.map{|col| "topics.#{col}"}).
      select('topics.*, count(votes.id) as votes')
```

Comment: Thank you Pinny, that works!  However, when I execute the PSQL above it is printed out in a nice format.  I'm personally finding this indirection of using ActiveRecord not a bonus. It's harder to write, harder to understand, and you do more work to get data out.  I guess if I knew ActiveRecord/ruby like I know SQL, I'd have a different opinion. But thanks! Your solution does work.

Comment: @Choppen5: ActiveRecord isn't designed to create 'reshaped' query projections very elegantly.  Its biggest strength is in working with scopes and joins across associations, the most common modeling requirement.  You can always revert to SQL fragments as I recommended here.  Or you can learn to use the more powerful, but quite complex, Arel interface directly (the ActiveRecord query interface is actually a wrapper for Arel).  Or you can use the Squeel gem which is a fairly easy to use wrapper for Arel.